# batch mode quoted parameters parsing

Tags: r

I'm trying to use my R script in batch mode, but R doesn't seem able to parse quoted parameters properly:

```
args=(commandArgs(TRUE))
for(i in 1:length(args)){
   print(paste('ARG ',i,args[[i]],sep=" "))
}
```

Then if a parameter with spaces and quotes is supplied, like:

```
R CMD BATCH "--args foo=2 bar=3 's=string with spaces'"  test-parameters.R output
```

the output is:

```
[1] "ARG  1 foo=2"
[1] "ARG  2 bar=3"
[1] "ARG  3 's=string"
[1] "ARG  4 with"
[1] "ARG  5 spaces'"
```

of course I'd like the third parameter to be `s='string with spaces'`: is there a way to obtain that?

Thank you!

Comment: is it safe to assume you are on mac or linux only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, R CMD BATCH acts a little weird.

Try this instead:

```
R --slave --vanilla --file=test-parameters.R --args foo=2 bar=3 "s=string with spaces" > output
```

The --slave and --vanilla options might be replaced with more suitable options as needed.

Comment: see also the littler package that makes a few things even easier, IMO: http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html

Answer (score 1):

To stick with R CMD BATCH, I ended passing the argument with a caret where a space is needed, and then performing a gsub("^"," ",argumentPassed,fixed=TRUE)

Batch Script

```
R CMD BATCH --no-restore "--args automationRDS='//networkLocation/folder/folder/my^filename^has^spaces.RDS'" "\\networkLocation\folder\folder\RScript.R"
```

Within R

```
automationRDS <- gsub("^"," ",automationRDS,fixed=TRUE)
```

I like the logging feature of R CMD BATCH vs Rscript